# What is the meaning of these blue crosses (x-like) in eastern Brandenburg?

Tags: germany, identify-this

I've been traveling by bike in eastern Brandenburg, Germany and have encountered at least 4 of those. My guess that it was somehow connected to camping or maybe boats? Couldn't find anything online, searching for `blue cross` is pretty hard.

[image: blue wooden cross against the fence]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

They are probably to signal political agreement with some causes.

For example, blue crosses are/were used to protest [for free public access to waterbanks without private fences](https://www.moz.de/lokales/beeskow/freie-ufer-blaue-kreuze-am-wegesrand-48837832.html) in eastern Brandenburg (which is probably what you've seen) and [against the building of the
Fehmarnbelttunnel](https://www.shz.de/regionales/schleswig-holstein/frist-abgelaufen-acht-klagen-gegen-fehmarnbelt-tunnel-id23806062.html) in northern Germany.